# How to deserialise JSON datetime with nanosecond precision using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to deserialise a JSON object using gson, but having issues when it comes to dates. The date is deserialised from the JSON object, but because the value in the JSON object is in nanoseconds, the value I get is slightly off of the expected value.

See the following code

**JSONClass**

```
public class JSONClass {
    private Date timestamp;

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class GsonTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").create();
        final String responseJSON = "{ \"timestamp\":\"2017-11-09 11:07:20.079364+00\" }";
        final JSONClass foo = gson.fromJson(responseJSON, new TypeToken<JSONClass>(){}.getType());
        System.out.println(foo.getTimestamp().toString());
    }
}
```

The output of the application is

```
Thu Nov 09 11:08:39 GMT 2017
```

When I expect it to be

```
Thu Nov 09 11:07:20 GMT 2017
```

I don't care about the nanosecond precision, so I'm happy for this to be truncated, but as I don't have control over the JSON format, I'm not sure the best way to do this.

**How can I get gson to deserialise the date correctly?**

Comment: The discrepacy between your observed and expected timestamps cannot be due to nanosecond precision, which component is far less than one whole second.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but if I truncate it myself (i.e to `2017-11-09 11:07:20.079+00`) I get the expected output.

Comment: Seems strange to me, in any case I don't work with GSON very often, so an upvote is all the help I can offer you.

Comment: I have the same behavior using Java without Gson. I can reproduced the bug using : Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2017-11-09 11:07:20.079364+00");
        System.out.println(d.toString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the precision available in `Date`, and with Java 8 it's best to use `LocalDateTime`. This also means that you will need a `TypeAdapter` as Gson doesn't work very well with `LocalDateTime`. This type adapter needs to be registered with Gson to deserialize (and potentially serialize) `LocalDateTime` objects from `String`s.

Something like the below should give you what you need.

**JSONClass**

```
public class JSONClass {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**LocalDateTimeDeserialiser**

```
static class LocalDateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;

        LocalDateTimeDeserializer(String datePattern) {
            this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), formatter);
        }
```

**Main**

```
public class GsonTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSx")).create();
        final String responseJSON = "{ \"timestamp\":\"2017-11-09 11:07:20.079364+00\" }";
        final JSONClass foo = gson.fromJson(responseJSON, new TypeToken<JSONClass>(){}.getType());
        System.out.println(foo.getTimestamp().toString());
    }
}
```